# Unable to close Outlook mailboxes

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange-2010

I have a user who has two Exchange mailboxes in Outlook that cannot be removed.  In fact I'm not sure why they are there at all because I cannot find evidence within Outlook's Accounts settings for these mailboxes.

I cannot right-click -> Close these two "Enquiries" mailboxes, Outlook advises to remove them from the Accounts settings:

[image: Outlook mailboxes that cannot be closed]

There is only one Exchange mailbox under Outlook Accounts, plus no additional Mailboxes added:

[image: Additional mailboxes]

Can someone please help?

Comment: Delete the Outlook profile entirely, and create a new one. To be sure, empty out the Outlook folder under AppSettings as well (I'm not sure of the exact location, but it'll be the one containing the OST files).

Comment: I had tried that - deleted Outlook profile & renamed the Outlook folders under Local\AppData & Roaming\AppData.

Comment: Last resort: there are a couple of registry branches you'll have to nuke as well then. Unfortunately I'm nowhere near a Windows machine right now, but it's under HKCU. Search for the account name or in your case, "Enquiries". There's the usual Microsoft\Outlook structure there. You'll know it when you see it. Make sure Outlook isn't running (check Task Manager to be sure.)

Comment: Oops that wasn't an update, it was an accidental copy/paste.  I attempted the removal of registry keys (as well as renaming Outlook folders under AppData & Local Settings), but the issue still remained.  Maybe the only way to get rid of this issue is to totally wipe MS Office & reinstall?!

Comment: Even removing Outlook will not remove the Outlook profile information in the HKEY Local User registry.

Answer (score 0):

The other mailbox that appeared out of nowhere was "[autodiscovered](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/673)" by outlook because the current user has "Full access" to that secondary mailbox.  Outlook is trying to be helpful.

-Tom Dragonetti